# Nested generic casting in Java

Tags: java, containers, javabeans, comparable, nested-generics

I am facing some issues while writing an abstract bean container class.

I created an interface **ImyAppsBean** :

```
public interface ImyAppsBean{}
```

Now I want to implement a sort method in my abstract container class. I would like to assume, that the instances of **ImyAppsBean** also implement the interface **Comparable**, so I can use **Collections.sort** for sorting my internal list of **ImyAppsBean** objects. Therefore I need to cast my list of **ImyAppsBean** objects to a list of **Comparable** objects, but don`t know how to do this. My code looks like this, the nested generics in line 6 cause a syntax error:

```
public abstract class AbstractBeanContainer(){

    protected static List<ImyAppsBean> beanList;

    protected static void sort(){
      Collections.sort((List<Comparable<ImyAppsBean>>) beanList);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force all implementations of your interface to implement `Comparable<ImyAppsBean>` by making your interface extend `Comparable<ImyAppsBean>`:

```
public interface ImyAppsBean extends Comparable<ImyAppsBean>
```

Then you would be able to call `Collections.sort(beanList)` without any cast.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface doesn't extend `Comparable`.
How do you want to cast `List<ImyAppsBean>` to `List<Comparable<ImyAppsBean>>` ? Besides, to sort a List, the cast is useless as it is enough if the generic of the `List` is an instance of `Comparable`.

Extend Comparable in the interface :

```
public interface ImyAppsBean extends Comparable<ImyAppsBean>{
...
}
```

Implement it in your concrete class :

```
public class MyAppsBean implements ImyAppsBean{

    ...
    public int compareTo(MyAppsBean o){
          ....
    }
    ...
}
```

And simplify your code in this way :

```
public abstract class AbstractBeanContainer(){

    protected static List<ImyAppsBean> beanList;

    protected static void sort(){
      Collections.sort(beanList);
    }
}
```